# Java calculator how to make backspace

Tags: java

I started learning programming a few days ago. I tried to make a calculator but i have one problem:
i don't know how to make backspace JButton.

```
buusun.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                tf.setText(text.getText().length()-1); 
            }

        });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I got a lot of hits in Google when searching for "java calculator backspace", including [this one](http://www.coderanch.com/t/620457/java/java/Implementing-backspace-button-calculator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    buusun.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            tf.setText(text.getText().substring(0, text.getText().length() - 1)); 
        }

    });
```

It uses the [`string.substring(start, end)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) method.
Note that you might need to adjust the exact variables you are using, as I'm not sure whether you need to get the value from `tf` or `text`, but this should provide the gist of what you want.